# Log URL's in a series of quick javascript redirects

Tags: javascript, browser, redirect

I click on a link, which sends me to another page that returns 200 OK, then redirects with Javascript in under a second. The next page does the same - a 200 OK followed by a quick Javascript redirect. Sometimes there are several of these pages in a row.

Is there a way to track the URL's in this series easily without having to muck around in the browser history? Or how would I build a tool that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/version.asp is kind of the de facto tool for this

Comment: Ah, I'm on a Mac. There aren't any browser extensions?

Comment: I'm also a fan of Fiddler.  It shows you all the network traffic so you can see everything thing that is happening even across pages.

Comment: ANY modern browser can show you this info: every browser has Developer Tools (Dragonfly for Opera, IE, Chrome) .. and you have Firebug for Firefox.

Comment: @LazyOne: The problem is any time the page refreshes the dev tools/firebug refresh too. I'd need to halt page execution long enough to log the URL.

Comment: @Kevin Firebug for Firefox for sure has "Persist" button that will remember the requests results between requests. Not sure about other browsers -- not using them that much.